# angular 2 function continue before return data from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a problem in Angular 2 that function continue work and does not waiting getting data from API.

HTTPHelper Class

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ReturnResultViewModel } from './ReturnResultViewModel';

export class HttpHelpers {

     _result: any = null;
     _errormsg: any = null;
     _returnResultViewModel: ReturnResultViewModel;    

     constructor(private http: Http) {
         this._returnResultViewModel = new ReturnResultViewModel();    
    }

    postaction(param: any, path: string) {    
        let body = JSON.stringify(param);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(path, body, options)
            .map((m:Response) =>  m.json())    
    }
}
```

HomeUserService Class

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpHelpers } from '../../../HttpHelpers';
import { usersHome } from "././Home.users.ViewModel";
import { ReturnResultViewModel } from "../../../ReturnResultViewModel";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
Injectable()


export class HomeUsersService extends HttpHelpers {    
    private _UrlLogin: string = "Accounts/getAllUsers";

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private _http: Http) {
        super(_http);    
    }
    private _usersHome: usersHome[];
    getAllUsers(): usersHome[]{

        alert(2);
         this.postaction(null, this._UrlLogin)
            .subscribe(result => 
                this._returnResultViewModel = result);


         if (this._returnResultViewModel == null)
         {
             alert("NULL");
             return null;
         }
         else {
             alert("Has DATA");
             this._usersHome = this._returnResultViewModel.result;
             alert(this._usersHome.length)
             return this._usersHome;
         }



    }
}
```

HomeUserComponent Class

```
export class HomeUserComponent implements OnInit{

    _usersHome: [usersHome];
    constructor( private _homeUsersService: HomeUsersService, private _router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
        alert(1);
        var x =  this._homeUsersService.getAllUsers();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid calling `subscribe` in your service, unless necessary. Let your service do all the logic manipulation, and only do a `subscribe` in your component.

In your service, change your `.subscribe` to `.map`:

```
export class HomeUsersService extends HttpHelpers {
    private _UrlLogin: string = "Accounts/getAllUsers";

    constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http: Http) {
        super(_http);
    }

    private _usersHome: usersHome[];

    getAllUsers(): usersHome[] {

        alert(2);
        this.postaction(null, this._UrlLogin)
            .map(result => {
                if (result === null) {
                    alert("NULL");
                    return null;
                } else {
                    alert("HAS DATA");
                    this._usersHome = result.result;
                    alert(this._usersHome.length);
                    return this._usersHome;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Now, since your service returns a correctly mapped Observables, you can handle the rest in your component:

```
export class HomeUserComponent implements OnInit {

    _usersHome: [usersHome];

    constructor(private _homeUsersService: HomeUsersService, private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        alert(1);
        this._homeUsersService.getAllUsers()
            .subscribe(users => {
                //do something to your users.
                let x = users;
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code within the `.subscribe()` is asynchronous. This means it is not executed right away, but sometime later.

If you have a code `x` that depends on the execution of the asynchronous bit, you have to place that `x` inside the `.subscribe()` part itself or use other mechanisms, like callbacks or promises.

Try as follows:

```
getAllUsers(): usersHome[]{

    alert(2);
     this.postaction(null, this._UrlLogin)
        .subscribe((result) => {                    // changed here

            this._returnResultViewModel = result;   // changed here


     if (this._returnResultViewModel == null)
     {
         alert("NULL");
         return null;
     }
     else {
         alert("Has DATA");
         this._usersHome = this._returnResultViewModel.result;
         alert(this._usersHome.length)
         return this._usersHome;
     }


   }                                               // added this
}
```

I placed the code that depends on the asynchronous part (`this._returnResultViewModel = result;`) inside the function that is given to `.subscribe()`.